# How to add youtube music video playing in background in Html

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, tags

#### Im making a website for pacman and its game with js, but I not sure how to add music from youtube to play in background. 

I tried this code but it doesnt work =((, please helppp.

`<iframe width="854" height="480" style="display:none;"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v2a5yMUmcp0?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=v2a5yMUmcp0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Theirs a free site that you can use, just make a embed code then paste it on your website, if you don't want to show it then you can add a css display='none' see link -> http://navarr.me/ytaudio/

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code, and it works just fine. Here is a demo using the exact code you showed.

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/14fgLv0g/embed/"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, now my pacman game version seems more entertaining

Comment: TBH, you already solved your problem. Sooo... yeah... I kinda feel useless :P